# Installing earlier version of Ankhsvn

Tags: visual-studio, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I installed Ankhsvn 2.3, but that assumes I'm using Subversion 1.7, which I'm not. Now I'm trying to install Ankhsvn 2.1, but it says that I'm unable to install because a newer version of the product is already installed.

So, how do I uninstall Ankhsvn 2.3? I can't find the uninstaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows design guideliness tell application developers that they should just add uninstallers to the Start->Control Panel->Software list. So this is where you can find the AnkhSVN uninstall (like that of any other MSI)

Adding an unnecessary uninstall icon in the program menu would even be a design error for a 'Designed for Windows' application.